# Identify two national flags from a picture (and/or video)

Tags: flag

In the [following picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Diplomatic_Quarter_(%E4%BD%BF%E9%A4%A8%E7%89%B9%E5%8D%80)_of_Taiwan_(%E4%B8%AD%E8%8F%AF%E6%B0%91%E5%9C%8B),_as_seen_from_Lane_101,_Tianmu_West_road_(%E5%A4%A9%E6%AF%8D%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF101%E5%B7%B7)_on_31_October_2017,_around_1PM_(Picture_4).jpg):

- Which flag is placed between the national flag of the **Dominican Republic** (7th from left) and the national flag of the **Republic of China (Taiwan)** (9th from left)?
- Which flag is placed between the national flag of the **Republic of Kiribati** (6th from right) and the national flag of the **Federation of Saint Christopher and Nevis** (4th from right)?

In case the flags can't be seen easily in the picture, one can look at [a movie montage in which they are waving](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Montage_of_national_flags_of_diplomatic_partners_waving_in_front_of_the_Diplomatic_Quarter_(%E4%BD%BF%E9%A4%A8%E7%89%B9%E5%8D%80)_of_Taiwan_(%E4%B8%AD%E8%8F%AF%E6%B0%91%E5%9C%8B),_as_seen_from_Lane_101,_Tianmu_West_road_(%E5%A4%A9%E6%AF%8D%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF101%E5%B7%B7)_on_31_October_2017,_around_1PM.webm), from the same date.

For your convenience, some stills from that movie, to help identifying the flags:

- [image: Flag 1]
- [image: Flag 2]

Comment: OK. The second flag is the national flag of the Republic of Nauru (see the video for more clarity). But I haven't figured out the first one yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text descriptions of both [still image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Diplomatic_Quarter_(%E4%BD%BF%E9%A4%A8%E7%89%B9%E5%8D%80)_of_Taiwan_(%E4%B8%AD%E8%8F%AF%E6%B0%91%E5%9C%8B),_as_seen_from_Lane_101,_Tianmu_West_road_(%E5%A4%A9%E6%AF%8D%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF101%E5%B7%B7)_on_31_October_2017,_around_1PM_(Picture_4).jpg) and [the video](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Montage_of_national_flags_of_diplomatic_partners_waving_in_front_of_the_Diplomatic_Quarter_(%E4%BD%BF%E9%A4%A8%E7%89%B9%E5%8D%80)_of_Taiwan_(%E4%B8%AD%E8%8F%AF%E6%B0%91%E5%9C%8B),_as_seen_from_Lane_101,_Tianmu_West_road_(%E5%A4%A9%E6%AF%8D%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF101%E5%B7%B7)_on_31_October_2017,_around_1PM.webm) claim that these flags are of **Trinidad and Tobago** and **Nauru**, correspondingly.

However, the text must be misleading; the first one is [Belize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belize)

[image: Belize flag]
<sub>Image courtesy of Wikipedia</sub>

And another one is, indeed, [Republic of Nauru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Nauru):

[image: Nauru flag]
<sub>Image courtesy of Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: The text descriptions are as such because I added them. My mistake. Thank you for pointing out that the flag is the national flag of Belize indeed. I have now changed the descriptions accordingly.